# Powerbi Tiles Embedurl Empty

Tags: tiles, powerbi

So a question about PowerBI tiles.

Firstly, I've been through all the documentation (that I can find) and downloaded the samples, which, by the way, do not work, and don't work in exactly the same way I'm experiencing.

I can retrieve the tiles from the Dashboard (which works perfectly well), the tiles themselves do *not* contain the embedurl necessary to put into an i-frame.

I've scoured, but can only find one or two other people talking about this issue, with no resolution.

Any help would be... helpful?

Cheers.